# Oracle ALTER [OBJECT_NAME] VS CREATE OR REPLACE [OBJECT]

Tags: oracle, alter

I am confusing with Oracle some objects I do modify with ALTER [OBJECT_NAME]  while others with CREATE OR REPLACE [OBJECT]
 some examples:
ALTER TABLE but no CREATE OR REPLACE?
ALTER VIEW vs CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW?
Why we can CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW but can't CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE?

what are differences? when to use ALTER or when CREATE OR REPLACE (for instance for view) can't find any good explanation on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Had there been a `create or replace table`, the data in it would disappear. The same goes for sequences. Views, packages, and such does not carry any real data, just metadata.
Before the alter table command existed there were a lot of trickery with scripts that renamed tables, created new ones and moved the data. It was not fun.